# Xcode12 beta 5 makes "library not found for -lGoogleUtilities" error

Tags: admob, ld, xcode12, google-ads-api

I downloaded Xcode12 beta 5 to apply Google Ads SDK v7.64 and AppTrackingTransparency framework to my app.
But when I build my project with Xcode12 beta 5, I meet "library not found for -lGoogleUtilities" even though I didn't change my project file anything.
When I use Xcode11 to build my project, it's okay.

Is it a bug of Xcode12? Or How can I fix the problem?

I use pod to setting and opened *.xcworkspace file to open project.

Comment: I tried it with Xcode12 beta6, but the result is the same. I have searched the internet about this issue and I tried all of the case. But I can't resolve this issue still.

Comment: When I build for a device, build is successful, but when I build for simulator, I meet this error with error message below too.  

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/....../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/......-dlqqmldfdujwshejtkrzrovcmqdo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities'

Answer (score 2):

Did you run at simulator, if that, add `x86_64` support(your tagrgets -> Build Settings -> VALID_ARCHS)for DEBUG.
[add description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5ibu.png)

Comment: Please provide with a comment only, if a comment can do the job, instead of posting an answer

See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)